# Angular JS filter an overview based on array of categories

Tags: html, angularjs, json

What I'm trying to do is create an overview that can be filtered based on a categories that are nested in an array of JSON objects.

The JSON of the items I want to create an overview of would look something like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "title",
  content: "content",
  categories: [{
      title: "cat1",
      descripton: "desc"
  },
  {
      title: "cat2",
      descripton: "desc"
  }]
},
{
  id: 2,
  title: "title",
  content: "content",
  categories: [{
      title: "cat3",
      descripton: "desc"
  },
  {
      title: "cat4",
      descripton: "desc"
  }]
}
```

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<select ng-model="catselect">
  <option>cat1</option>
  <option>cat2</option>
  <option>cat3</option>
  <option>cat4</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in array | filter: {ARRAY OF CATEGORIES: catselect}">

  </li>
</ul>
```

Currently I have no clue how to get this to work. The (I think) most obvious solution should've been someting like `filter: {categories.title: catselect}` but apparently it isn't. As far as I know no other questions on Stackoverflow tackle this problem. I'm very interested to see if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this to see if it works? I didnt actually tested it.

```
filter: { categories: { title: catselect } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your trouble! This solution solution didn't work though :(

Comment: Try variations of my answer like: filter: { categories: { title: catselect } } or others, this actually worked for me when i have an object inside my object, didnt try with an array inside an object..

Comment: That actually works! :) Can you edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Eddited the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

A custom filter will work

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("test", function($scope) {

    $scope.array = [{
      id: 1,
      title: "title",
      content: "content",
      categories: [{
        title: "cat1",
        descripton: "desc"
      }, {
        title: "cat2",
        descripton: "desc"
      }]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: "title2",
      content: "content",
      categories: [{
        title: "cat3",
        descripton: "desc"
      }, {
        title: "cat4",
        descripton: "desc"
      }]
    }]
  })
  .filter("filterByCat", function() {
    return function(input, catselect) {
      if (catselect != undefined) {
        var f = []
        angular.forEach(input, function(el) {
          if ((el.categories.filter(function(cat) {
            return cat.title == catselect
          })).length > 0) f.push(el);
        })
        return f;
      } else {
        return input;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <select ng-model="catselect">
    <option>cat1</option>
    <option>cat2</option>
    <option>cat3</option>
    <option>cat4</option>
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in array | filterByCat:catselect">{{item.title}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```